# Is it a valid scenario to have a smartcard that does not have a default container?

Tags: windows-7, authentication, smartcard

This question is about hosting smartcard login certificates that are used to log into Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.  I've read that in the 2000/XP timeframe, one could have only one such certificate on the smartcard and that had to be in the default container.  In Windows 7 I've read that several smartcard login certificates can be present on the card and am wondering if one of them still needs to be in the default container?  I'm also wondering if on Windows 7 having a default container on the smartcard is required at all?

Thanks much,  Eugen

Answer (score 0):

smart card always has default container. if it's deleted than CSP will mark another container as default. Read [here more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404300%28v=ws.10%29)